# How to show questions with my skills?

Tags: feature-request

In Questions tab, there are no questions with my skills.
So I cannot answer any questions.
How can I See all the questions and questions with my skills?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+or+%5Bc%5D+or+%5Bpython%5D+closed%3Ano+answers%3A0+score%3A1+protected%3A0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be to find tags that correspond to your skills. You can then look at questions that contain those tags.

If you go to the tags page you can type in partial tag names till you find one or more that match your skill set. Click on each tag to find the questions containing that tag and you can look to see if you can answer them.